# after login django-allauth login page doesn't show good?

Tags: django, django-allauth

On my django project,I added django-alluth for google login.But after click google login button in
my login.html,the page which will login is:

[image]

after I clicked continue button google login the page is shownn at the bottom:

[image]

I want to from here,At my  login template when I clicked to login with google button directly second piture will be shown.How can I do that? Because first picture doesn't look good.I want to directly jump the other image.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I believe the issue was in the SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS variable. Make sure that the variable is set in the settings.py file like below (I use dotenv and keep my variables in a .env file, but you can also set the variables in the admin page under Social Applications > add social application.

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'google': {
        'APP': {
            'client_id': os.getenv('GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'),
            'secret': os.getenv('GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET'),
        },
        "AUTH_PARAMS": {
            "access_type": "online",
        },
    }
}
```

Documentation: https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

use javascript to when you clicked on the login with google through javascript it will direct you to the ugly page but again use js in that page to submit that form automitaclly it will solve your problem..

this code should be in  templates/account/login

```
{% extends "layout/base.html"%}
{% load socialaccount %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container py-3">
  <div class="row justify-content-center mt-5">
    <div class="col-md-6 py-2">
      <div class="card p-3">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h2 class="card-title text-center login-text">Login Form</h2>
          <hr class="text-primary" />
          <form method="post" action="{% url 'account_login' %}">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="mb-3">
              <input
                type="email"
                class="form-control py-3"
                id="email"
                placeholder="Enter your email"
                name="email"
              />
              {{ form.email.errors }}
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
              <input
                type="password"
                class="form-control py-3"
                id="password"
                placeholder="Enter your password"
                name="password"
              />
              {{ form.password.errors }}
              <!-- Display password field errors -->
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary w-100 py-2">
              Login
            </button>
            <hr class="my-3" />
            
          </form>
          <a id="google-auth-link" href="{% provider_login_url 'google' %}"><button id="google-login-button" class="btn btn-danger w-100 py-2">
            <svg
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              width="16"
              height="16"
              fill="currentColor" 
              class="bi bi-google"
              viewBox="0 0 16 16"
            ></svg>
            Login with Google
          </button>
        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
{% block scripts%}
<script>
  document.getElementById("google-auth-link").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    window.location.href = "{% provider_login_url 'google' %}";
  });
</script>
{% endblock%}






{% comment %} <div class="login-container">
      <h2>Login Form</h2>
      <form>
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required>
        
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required>
        
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
      </form>

      <!-- Add the Google login button -->
      <a id="google-auth-link" href="{% provider_login_url 'google' %}" class="google-btn">
        <img src="" alt="" class="btn-google">
        Login with Google
    </a> {% endcomment %}
    
{% comment %}  
</div>

{% endblock %} {% endcomment %}


and placed this code in templates/socialaccount/login.html

<form id="google-login-form" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit" style=" display: none;">
    </button>
 </form>
 
 <script>
    window.onload = function() {
       document.getElementById("google-login-form").submit();
    };`enter code here`
 </script>
```